# Creating 2 "cartridges" of cumulative sum with conditions using SQL

Tags: sql, sum, window-functions, vertica

I need to create 2 cumulative sums based on the value type, for example:

I have values of incoming stock units from 2 types: A and B. and I also have records of outgoing stock units.

If we have enough stock of type "A" it should taken out of type A, if not- it should be taken out of type B. so basically I need to crate the columns "A stock" and "B stock" below, representing the current balance of each type.

I tried using cumulative sum but I'm having trouble with the condition... is there a way to write this query without using a loop ? ( Vertica DB)

In table below A_stock and B_stock are the final result I need to create

```
ID  Type    In      OUT     A stock B stock  Order_id
1   A       100     0       100     0        1
1   B       50      0       100     50       2
1   A       100     0       200     50       3
1   -       0       -200    0       50       4
1   -       0       -10     0       40       5
1   B       50      0       0       90       6
1   A       40      0       40      90       7
1   -       0      -20      20      90       8
2   A       30      0       30      0        1
2   B       20      0       30      20       2
2   A       10      0       40      20       3
2   -       0       -20     20      20       4
```

Comment: Your problem seems to suggest that your rows are ordered.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* data sets.  There is no ordering unless you explicitly have a column with the ordering.

Comment: As @GMB pointed out, you need an ordering column to start with. But, secondly - as the following results depend on whatever happened previously ( 1. the running sum; 2. the decision based on the results of the previous running sums and balances), you will need a recursive query. And the `RECURSIVE WITH` clause does not exist (yet  ?) in Vertica. The workaround would be to write as many Common  Table Expressions in the `WITH` clause as you expect iterations to be necessary. And that can become ugly.

Comment: @marcothesane, yes, of course you are right, to be clear, I do have a way to order the results (added ordering column to the example) unfortunately I think you are right, I don't see a way to do it without a recursive query...

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions - but you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows, I assumed `ordering_id`:

```
select t.*,
    sum(case when type = 'A' then in + out else 0 end) over(partition by id order by ordering_id) a_stock,
    sum(case when type = 'B' then in + out else 0 end) over(partition by id order by ordering_id) b_stock
from mytable t
```

This assumes that you want the stock on a per-`id` basis; if that's not the case, just remove the `partition` clause from the `over()` clause.

Comment: You did not take into consideration the rows with `NULL`  for the `type` column - those where something is taken away from the stock and where the trouble with the decisions begins, @GMT ...